# Can't use redux-observable with Stencil@one : "Class constructor Observable cannot be invoked without 'new'" error on ActionsObservable class

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, redux-observable, stenciljs

I have a Stencil component library using @Stencil/redux, redux, redux-observable and redux-actions. Everything worked fine before but I'm trying to upgrade to Stencil@One (1.0.0-beta.5).

I have now an error during the Redux store creation. This is my store configuration :

```js
import { Store, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { createEpicMiddleware } from 'redux-observable';
import { rootEpic } from './epic';

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware();
export const ogodStore: Store<OgodState> = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware));

epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);
```

The error occurs on applyMiddleware call and is the following :

```
TypeError: Class constructor Observable cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at new ActionsObservable (chunk-f18fe9c6.js:3744)
    at epicMiddleware (chunk-f18fe9c6.js:3830)
    at chunk-f18fe9c6.js:4579
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at chunk-f18fe9c6.js:4578
    at createStore (chunk-f18fe9c6.js:4043)
    at chunk-f18fe9c6.js:4716
```

I am so confused over the years by the different javascript module types and targets... But here's what I know :

- This error is caused by this specific code inside redux-observable :

```
(ActionsObservable.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(ActionsObservable)).call(this)
```

- It is using `call(this)` to construct a ActionsObservable object, which is dependent on rxjs's `Observable` class
- In my Typescript configuration I use what stencil created and it's still the same for new projects (module: 'esnext', target: 'es2017')

`Observable` from rxjs does not support this ?! It is a class that should be constructed using ES6 syntax `new` because it is supported by browsers now ?

I'd really like to know if I should create an issue in redux-observable's Github ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [issue](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/644) has been created since nobody answered. Hope we get news on it soon...

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue following the github link provided by @Elvynia -

Install redux-observable-es6-compat and Import -

```
import { createEpicMiddleware, combineEpics } from 'redux-observable-es6-compat';
```

instead of

```
import { createEpicMiddleware, combineEpics } from 'redux-observable';
```

Comment: The reason 'redux-observable-es6-compat' works, is because it uses the typescript compiler instead of babel being compiled to es2015